Xamarin Forms - libmonosgen-2.0.so & android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce
Issue 1 [libmonosgen-2.0.so] mono_os_cond_timedwait
Issue 2: Native method - android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce
We are facing this issue from current playstore build. From ourside we tested a wholeday to reproduce this but we cant able to reproduce.
can anyone give us any idea to resolve it. please
We have checked the stack trace for this issue in appcenter as well.

Have you found something? We are experiencing same problem with our Xamarin application deployed to Google Play after update.
